# Getting XML from external webservice

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I'm doing a mashup as a personal project and I'm trying to use a webservice I found.

The webservice can be found here:

http://www.html2xml.nl/Services/html2xml/version1/Html2Xml.asmx?op=HtmlString2XmlNode

When I try to call it via ajax I always get the following message (using FireFox 7 in this case):

> Error de lectura XML: no se encuentra elemento Ubicación:
>   moz-nullprincipal:{c46bfb1b-719d-490b-8293-a2eabd2ac15a} Número de
>   línea 1, columna 1:

Google translated version :

> XML read error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal
>   {719d-490b-c46bfb1b-8293-a2eabd2ac15a} Number of line 1, column 1:

I tried several ways ($ajax, JQuery.get, etc) and I always crash into the same wall...

You could try for example : http://www.html2xml.nl/Services/html2xml/version1/Html2Xml.asmx/Url2XmlNode?urlAddress=www.google.es

It seems to work if you execute it in the browser, but I don't know if the problem is a cross domain issue or the output format of the XML...

Does anybody know how I could solve this? (I've had a look at similar posts with no clear solution).

The code im using is:

```
var envelope =
                    {
                    urlAddress: "www.google.es"
                    }

$.ajax({
                    url: "http://www.html2xml.nl/Services/html2xml/version1/Html2Xml.asmx/Url2XmlNode",
                    dataType: 'xml',
                    data : envelope,
                    dataFilter: function (data, type) {
                    alert(data);
                    alert(type);
                    }
                    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your jQuery code ?

Answer (score 1):

The webservice you are using isn't returning valid xml from google's page.  If you View Source on google's page, shortly after the  tag you will see this tag:

```
<textarea id=csi style=display:none></textarea>
```

If you look in the same place of the Source from the webservice it converts the empty  node into a self-closing tag, but leaves a hanging CDATA tag after it.

```
<textarea id="csi" style="display:none" /><![CDATA[]]>
```

If your dataFilter function is firing, you can do a replace('`<![CDATA[]]>`','') on the response but I think your error is happening before that.  In that case change the dataType to "text" and if the dataFilter function remove the empty CDATA's and convert the text string into an xml object to return.  Might take a little playing around with it to get it to work and I also saw something about Converters that you may want to look into if you have problems.